# How can I store visitor's IP in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function which takes care of logs:

```
function writeLog($db, $msg) {
if( ($remote_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) == '') {
$remote_addr = "REMOTE_ADDR_UNKNOWN";
}
$remote_addr = $db->escape_string($remote_addr);
```

All it does is store this: `::1` as an IP. My PC is clearly connected to the internet. What am I not getting?

Comment: Could it be the fact that I'm using my pc as a server for php and it sees it as 127:0:0:1 ?

Comment: ::1 is your local address. If you are connecting to your local server, it is normal behaviour.

Comment: ::1 is the ipv6 representation of 127.0.0.1, so yes, that is your IP address.